# Possible options to collect Cassandra Monitoring metrics

Tags: monitoring, jmx, cassandra-2.0

I want to collect different metrics ( like read/write latency, memory usage, heap size, cpu usage, compaction count etc) for Cassandra cluster and that information will be used by other third party monitoring tool.
So I got to know options like

- nodetool ( it internally used jmx apis)
- jmx api ( mbean)
- jconsole ( a single Cassandra process can track and internally it will read data using jmx on that machine)

However here a few queries :

- Is this correct that nodetool doesn't provide all information that directly jmx can provide?
- If I decide to collect metrics directly using JMX api, then does my monitoring application has to give separate call for each node in Cassandra cluster? So if I have 50 nodes and jmx is running on call nodes, then will there 50 calls to collect say read latency from each host of cluster?
- Is there any way where data from all cluster nodes will be gathered at one place like jmx server then monitoring tool can read data in single machine call?
- How nodetool utility is using jmx APIs to read data from all nodes from cluster?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this correct that nodetool doesn't provide all information that directly jmx can provide?

Correct. Nodetool wasn't build as an reporting solution and does not focus on showing performance metrics. Therefor a lot of metrics provided by JMX are not covered by nodetool.

> If I decide to collect metrics directly using JMX api, then does my monitoring application has to give separate call for each node in Cassandra cluster?

Yes. Another option would be to have Cassandra *push* metrics to a specified endpoint. As an example, you could configure Cassandra to [push data to Graphite](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/pluggable-metrics-reporting-in-cassandra-2-0-2) or any other backend supported by [metrics-reporter-config](https://github.com/addthis/metrics-reporter-config).

> Is there any way where data from all cluster nodes will be gathered at one place like jmx server then monitoring tool can read data in single machine call?

Practically all Cassandra monitoring solutions will save gathered metrics internally and allow to query them later. I'd suggest to have a look at [existing solutions](https://cassandra-zone.com/performance-monitoring/#monitoring-platforms:cc05611fd873a7cd9f74d7c5b2563b10) to find out more.

> How nodetool utility is using jmx APIs to read data from all nodes from cluster?

Nodetool will only connect to a single host.

Comment: You should be able to [use your own reporter](https://github.com/addthis/metrics-reporter-config/blob/master/reporter-config-base/src/test/resources/sample/generic.yaml). Another option would be to implement the Graphite or Ganglia protocol.

Comment: Thanks Stefan.  I tried metrics-reporter-config to put all metrics in a csv file. That I could get working. Also I noticed that metrics mentioned at http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Metrics are the only possible to configure in YAML file as patterns. However in this option also, metrics file will be generated on each node and then my reporting tool should gather those metrics csv file from each Cassandra node periodically. Is this my assumption correct?